# winston saves color formatter in text, how to remove this but still show color?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, logging, winston

I am trying to create a logging module using `winston` as the logging framework. It allows me to specify colors, which is quite nice if the transport is `Console`, but if I were to define two transports, one `Console`, one `File`, it will actually save the terminal formatter string in the text, which will be saved in the file.

```
const { addColors, createLogger, format, transports } = require('winston');

const { combine, colorize, printf, timestamp } = format;

const logFormat = printf((info) => {
  return `[${info.timestamp}] ${info.level}: ${info.message}`;
});

const rawFormat = printf((info) => {
  return `[${info.timestamp}] ${info.level}: ${info.message}`;
});

const config = require('../config');

const logger = createLogger({
  level: config.DEBUG,
  format: combine(
    colorize(),
    timestamp({ format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss' }),
    logFormat,
  ),
  transports: [
    new transports.File({
      filename: 'combined.log',
    }),
    new transports.Console({ format: combine(timestamp(), rawFormat) }),
  ],
});

addColors({
  debug: 'white',
  error: 'red',
  info: 'green',
  warn: 'yellow',
});

module.exports = logger;
```

Console will look like this:

```
[2018-06-12 15:54:14] info: Listening on port 9000
```

Where `info` is colorized to green, but if i look at the `combine.log` file, it will show as:

```
[2018-06-12 15:54:14] [32minfo[39m: Listening on port 9000
```

Is it possible to log raw text to a file, but still show colors in terminal?

If not, is there another library that allows for this? Say `bunyan`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't know if u need this anymore but late is better than never.

Basically you just need to drop `colorzie()`from general format that you have defined then use it in the specify transports you want to show color.

```
var options = {
    console: {
        handleExceptions: true,
        level: 'debug',
        format: combine(colorize(), myFormat)
    },
    verbose: {
        filename: './logs/debug/mobile_api-%DATE%.log',
        level: 'debug',
        format: combine(myFormat)
    },
}
const logger = winston.createLogger({
levels: myCustomLevels.levels,
transports: [
    new transports.Console(options.console),
    new transports.file(options.verbose),
]
});
```

With this, when the log get printed in the console, you can see color and when write to file, it won't show any color code at all.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `uncolorized` method from `winston.format`. Read about it in [logform's documentation](https://github.com/winstonjs/logform#uncolorize).